# passphrase type page for a raffle

Tags: javascript, html

I was planning on using this password type style to let users check if they won. The codes are sent in an email then they come here to check if they won. If this was just for one winner the current system would work but i would like to add 5 and confirmPassword only allows one "code" to be valid. Is there anyway to add multiple valid ones?

```
<form>
    <label for="pswd">ENTER YOUR RAFFLE NUMBER HERE</label>
        <br>
    <input type="password" id="pswd" class="box" placeholder="test" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnSearch').click(); return false;}"/>
        <br>
    <input type="button" class="confirm" id="btnSearch" value="Check Results" onclick="checkPswd();" />
</form> 

</div>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
        var confirmPassword = "SampleCode";
        var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
             window.location="winner.html";
        }
        else{
            window.location="loser.html";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know, when you declare the `confirmPassword` variable in your JavaScript, it's client-side, meaning whoever visits your page can view the code simply by pressing `Ctrl + U` in their browser.

Comment: yes I am aware, the reason im not worried about that is that im going to confirm it through seeing if that user was truly sent that code in their email or not. Thank you for the heads up tho!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array in Javascript:

```
const confirmPassword = ["SampleCode1", "SampleCode2", "SampleCode3","SampleCode4","SampleCode5"];
if(confirmPassword.includes(password)){
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Completely solved it!!!!